# C++17 copy constructor, deep copy on std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, recursion, c++17, deep-copy, unordered-map

I am having trouble implementing the copy constructor that is required to perform deep copies on my prefab child actor, which is

```
std::unordered_map<unsigned, PrefabActor *> child_actor_container;
```

It needs to be able to recurse too, as the `PrefabActor *` inside maybe have another layer of child actor container.

Something like this:

```
 layer
    1st   | 2nd   | 3rd
    Enemy
         Enemy_Body
                  Enemy_Head
                  Enemy_hand and etc
         Enemy_Weapon
```

Here my implementation:

```
class DataFileInfo
{
public:
    DataFileInfo(std::string path, std::string filename );
    DataFileInfo(const DataFileInfo & rhs);
    virtual ~DataFileInfo();
    // all other functions implemented here
private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> resource_info;
    bool selection;
};

class PrefabActor : public DataFileInfo
{
public:

    PrefabActor(std::string path, std::string filename , std::string object_type, PrefabActor * parent_actor = nullptr);
    PrefabActor(const PrefabActor & rhs);

    ~PrefabActor();

    // all other function like add component, add child actor function are here and work fine 

private:
    unsigned child_prefab_actor_key; // the id key
    PrefabActor* parent_prefab_actor; // pointer to the parent actor

    std::unordered_map<ComponentType, Component*> m_ObjComponents; // contains a map of components like mesh, sprite, transform, collision, stats, etc.

    //I need to be able to deep copy this unordered map container and be able to recursive deep copy 
    std::unordered_map<unsigned, PrefabActor *> child_actor_container; // contains all the child actors

    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> prefab_actor_tagging; // contains all the tagging

};
```

Comment: If you want deep copy, why use pointers? Recursion is a non-issue, you need to implement the copy ctor of PrefabActor regardless.

Comment: which pointer you mean? you mean  std::unordered_map<unsigned, PrefabActor *> as PrefabActor * ?

Comment: I mean, why not `std::unordered_map<unsigned, PrefabActor>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to manually copy the entries:

```
PrefabActor(const PrefabActor & rhs)
{
    for(const auto& entry:  rhs.child_actor_container)
    {
        child_actor_container[entry.first] = new PrefabActor(*entry.second);
    }
}
```

Of course, you need to change the children's parent object as well.

You should indicate who owns the `PrefabActor` objects as well. There is a potential memory leak here.

Comment: for (auto it = rhs.child_actor_container.begin(); it != rhs.child_actor_container.end(); ++it , ++child_key)
 {
  PrefabActor * child_prefab = new PrefabActor(*(it->second));
  child_prefab->SetParentPointer(this);
  child_actor_container.emplace(child_key, child_prefab);
 }

is this ok?

Comment: What is `child_key`? I thought you wanted a deep clone. If you have additional ids, then yes, you have to adapt this code to things you didn't put in your question.

Comment: child_key just a unsigned value which is child_prefab_actor_key

Comment: Oh, OK. As I've said, you need to adapt the code to the specifics of how you track and identify your objects.